# Passing textfile and Creating new Tuple when there is space

Tags: python, file-io, tuples

I have a text file that I would like to pass to python and create a tuple every time a new space comes up a new tuple is created.

Lets say for example I have the following file

```
land, 3
-4,-2
4,3

ocean, 5
3,4
-6,5
5,6
```

my aim is to create a tuple for the first one, then when we hit the space another tuple is created for the second and so on until we get to the last.

Comment: What specifically do you want the output to be?

Comment: By "space" do you mean blank line? And what do you want the tuple to look like. Give an example.

Comment: @ooga, yes by space I mean new line

Comment: @MichaelBoselowitz, should look something like `"land"(0,3), (-4,-2), (4,3), "ocean",(0,5),(3,4),(-6,5), (5,6)`

Comment: @user3556735 what kind of object is that? A list? a dict?

Comment: @YuvalAdam its a list

Comment: You do not have a comma here `"land"(0,3)` but you have a comma here  `"ocean",(0,5)`

Comment: Sorry! Thanks @shaktimaan "land",(0,3), (-4,-2), (4,3), "ocean",(0,5),(3,4),(-6,5), (5,6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution. The wanted output is quite strange.

```
fp = open('test.txt', 'r')
file_contents = fp.read()
result = []
for split in file_contents.split('\n\n'):
    split = ','.join(split.split('\n'))
    split = ''.join(split.split(' '))
    split = split.split(',')
    for x in range(0, len(split)-1, 2):
        if x == 0:
            result.append(split[x])
            result.append((0, int(split[x+1])))
        else:
            result.append((int(split[x]), int(split[x+1])))
print result
```

Produces:

```
['land', (0, 3), (-4, -2), (4, 3), 'ocean', (0, 5), (3, 4), (-6, 5), (5, 6)]
```

Comment: My question to separate the tuples so when `result[0]` is called land and ocean are displayed